# What effect does using two different forms of solder mask on the same PWB have?

Tags: pcb, solder-mask

We found some PWBs that seem to have both film and liquid solder mask applied on the board. I have never encountered this before and was curious to see if this is acceptable for use.

Comment: I haven't heard of that either, unless perhaps you are referring to a conformal coating, in which case it would cover the parts on the PCB too, not just the raw PCB.  Post a picture (and remember to size and crop it appropriately).

Comment: Was it designed for any special application? High-Voltage, high-radiation/ionization, high-temp, etc...?

Comment: It's possible it was due to rework.

Answer (score 1):

Recognizing that there are a lot of assumptions here about the material specifications involved...

I spoke with two of our partner factories and they both said the same thing:

1. This is typically a result of rework, where the original soldermask was partially removed for some reason and needed to be reapplied post-hoc.
2. Should still meet spec -- meaning, there are no anticipated concerns as a result of the mixed process. Some overlap between the masked areas was suggested to ensure that you maintain complete coverage over the full temperature range.
3. If needed for a "special" application (life/safety critical, aerospace, etc) then recertification/testing is required.